# In SQLite, how can I update a column in TABLE A with the values from a column in TABLE B?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

Need help with this as I m having no luck.

Table A

```
id   groupid   
 1     100   
 2     101   
 3     102
```

Table B

```
groupid   newid  
 100        100  
 101        100   
 102        100
```

Update Table A so that Table A becomes

```
id   groupid   
 1     100   
 2     100   
 3     100
```

which uses TableB to get the newid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite doesn't support joins in updates, but you could use a subquery. try something like this:

```
update a
set groupid = coalesce(
 (select newid from b where groupid = a.groupid limit 1),
 groupid
);
```

Comment: if you know there is exactly one row in b for every row in a, then the limit 1 and coalesce shouldn't be necessary. but better safe than sorry.